# SAS filepath with variable parts

Tags: sas

I am trying to iterate over a list of different files and input them.

```
DO Year = 2000 to 2021 by 1;
        filename fileftp ftp year+'.csv.gz' host='ftp.abcgov' 
        cd='/pub/' user='anonymous'
        pass='XXXX' passive recfm=s debug;
        INFILE fileftp NBYTE=n;
END;
```

How do I get it so that year is included in the file name?
Currently, when I try this (`year+'.csv.gz'`) it is trying to recognize year as an option incorrectly.

Comment: Did you try the FILEVAR= option on the INFILE statement?

Comment: If you files are really GZIPPED you will need to first move them locally before you can uncompress them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the SAS macro facility for this. Since your file is zipped, you'll also need to unzip it before importing the data.

```
%macro importData;
    %do year = 2000 to 2021;
        filename fileftp ftp "&year..csv.gz" 
            host  = 'ftp.abcgov'
            cd    = '/pub/' 
            user  = 'anonymous'
            pass  = 'XXXX' 
            recfm = s 
            passive 
            debug
        ;

        filename download temp;
        
        /* Download the file to a temporary local space */
        %let rc = %sysfunc(fcopy(fileftp, download));

        /* Unzip the file */
        filename unzip "%sysfunc(pathname(download))" gzip;

        /* Read the data and output it by year */
        proc import 
            file = unzip
            out  = want&year.
            dbms = csv
            replace;
        run;

    %end;
%mend;
%importData;
```

If `fcopy` does not work for you, you can use a data step to write one file to another.

```
data _null_;   
   infile fileftp;
   file download;
   input;
   put _INFILE_ ;
run;
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that if this were a normal filename, you could use `filevar` in the data step; but with a `filename ftp` that isn't an option (nor with any of the other 'group' filenames).